# How can I add newline for IPython.display.Latex output?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I try to print out the 2 matrix objects with aligned using the Latex object, but adding `\\`  does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

```py
from IPython.display import display, Math,Latex

s = r"$$ \text{A } = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3\\1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\3 & 3 & 3\end{matrix}\right] \\  \text{B } = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\3 & 3 & 3 & 1\end{matrix}\right] $$"

display(Latex(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$$` at the beginning and at the end of your latex string use the following:

```
s = r"""
\begin{align*}

 #your matrices code

\end{align*}
"""
```